# Qt, low cost way to display only part of large QImage

Tags: qt, audio, scroll, qpainter, qimage

I draw frequency spectrum of WAV file inside QImage (example: http://savepic.net/2350314.jpg). The WAV file may be long enough to not fit into screen considering good time resolution.

I need to be able to srcoll through entire file fast enough, possibly without filesystem reading operations.

So i have to keep large QImage in memory for fast scrolling. Another desigion would be slower, because it would require me to redraw QImage (QImages) every time user scrolls a screen.

Assuming the desigion with keeping large QImage in memory (1024x50000, for example) i must be able to display some part of that large QImage in the program window.

What is the solution with lowest cost? Using QScrollArea or maybe using QPainter method drawImage() with offset arguments?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely build a small custom widget and reimplement its paint() method with a QPainter (and scrolling with offsets etc).

Using [QPixmap](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html) for showing the needed parts of the image should be faster then natively drawing (a part of) a QImage.

Comment: But how QPixmap differs from QImage for that usage?

Comment: It's designed and optimized for showing images on screen, see http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#details